# how to use hide show in while loop with different ids

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**HTML**

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
    $ad++;
    $sql1=mysql_query("select *from company where com_id='$row[com_id]'");
    $row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1);

?>
    <tr>
    <input type="hidden" id="comid" name="comid" value="<?php echo $row1[com_id];?>"/>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/mobile.png" width="18" height="18" border="0" alt="Mobile"></td>
        <td class="comm-details"><strong>Mobile</strong></td>
        <td align="center">:</td>
        <td class="comm-details"><?php if($row1['mobile1']!='') { ?> <a id="showmobile<?php echo $row1[com_id];?>">View Mobile Number</a> <span id="shwmb<?php echo $row1[com_id];?>" style="display:none"><?php echo $row1['mobile1'];}else{ echo 'Not Available';}?></td>
    </tr>
}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var comid = $('#comid').val();
    $("#showmobile" + comid).click(function() {
        $("#shwmb" + comid).show();
        $("#shwmb" + comid).hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Now I want to show the mobile number when the customer clicks on `View Mobile Number`.  It currently only works on the first viewed company, not for subsequent companies.

When I change the event handling to listen to the class instead of the id, clicking on any one company's `View Mobile Number` will display the mobile numbers of all companies on the page.

Neither solution is working properly.  What am I doing wrong, and how do I make this work?

Comment: Can you please tidy your code - if you'd like help at least make it easy to read

Comment: I just want hide show work properly in while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as like below:

```
<?php
$ad = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
    $ad++;
    $sql1 = mysql_query("select *from company where com_id='$row[com_id]'");
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
    ?>
    <tr>
    <input type="hidden" id="comid" name="comid" value="<?php echo $row1[com_id]; ?>"/>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="images/mobile.png" width="18" height="18" border="0" alt="Mobile"></td>
        <td class="comm-details"><strong>Mobile</strong></td>
        <td align="center">:</td>
        <td class="comm-details">
            <?php if ($row1['mobile1'] != '') { ?> 
            <a id="showmobile<?php echo $row1[com_id]; ?>" onclick="return showmobile(<?php echo $row1[com_id]; ?>)">View Mobile Number</a> 
                <span id="shwmb<?php echo $row1[com_id]; ?>" style="display:none">
                    <?php echo $row1['mobile1']; ?>
                </span>
            <?php
            } else {
                echo 'Not Available';
            }
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }
?>

<script>
    function showmobile(id) {
        if($("#shwmb" + id).css('display') == 'none') {
            $("#shwmb" + id).show();
        }else {
            $("#shwmb" + id).hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Correct me if i m wrong but it will work only for first row isint it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put unique value in the ID or CLASS of the line.

```
<input type="hidden" id="comid<?php echo $row['ID']?>" name="comid" value="<?php echo $row1[com_id];?>"/>
```

and after that in the javascript code you just specify the id along with the id_name and id_value.

Comment: how can I specify this in js??

Comment: See, you have to use the loop within the javascript function. I also face that type of problem once. And using this technique it was solved and accurately works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for your purpose:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_page_data)) {
    $ad++;
    $sql1=mysql_query("select *from company where com_id='$row[com_id]'");
    $row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1);

?>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" id="input-<?php echo $row1[com_id];?>" name="input-<?php echo $row1[com_id];?>" value="<?php echo $row1[com_id];?>"/>
            <img src="images/mobile.png" width="18" height="18" border="0" alt="Mobile">
        </td>
        <td class="comm-details"><strong>Mobile</strong></td>
        <td align="center">:</td>
        <td class="comm-details"><?php if($row1['mobile1']!='') { ?> <a id="showmobile<?php echo $row1[com_id];?>" class="showmobile">View Mobile Number</a> <span id="shwmb<?php echo $row1[com_id];?>" style="display:none"><?php echo $row1['mobile1'];}else{ echo 'Not Available';}?></td>
    </tr>
}

<script>
$(function () {
    $(".showmobile").click(function() {
        var comid = $(this).attr("id").replace("showmobile","");
        $("#shwmb" + comid).toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

The first change is to use `$row1[com_id]` in the `id` and `name` attributes for the hidden input field.  This will allow the hidden fields to be separate from one another, as `id` has to be unique on a page; `name` should also be unique.

Next, a class was added to the `showmobile` link, so that we can install a single class-level click handler.  The click handler will extract the `com_id` from the `showmobile` element and use it to change the visibility of the `shwmb` element, using jQuery `toggle`.

Some light restructuring has been done and some significant reformatting.  The hidden input field was added to the first `td` element, so that it doesn't interfere with the structure of the table.

Also, the `$result_page_data` variable name was corrected.